# Determining sample space and random variable for a construction of random maximal P-graph

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-graphs

> Let $P$ be a graph property that is preserved by the removal of edges.
>
> We give a construction of a Random maximal $P-$graph, denoted
>   $\textbf{M}_n(P)$, as follows:
>
> 1. Fix $V=\{1,2,...,n\}$, $K_n=\text{complete graph on vertex set} \; V$, $E^0=\text{initial edge set}=\emptyset.$
> 2. For each $i \ge 0$, if $F^i=\{e \in K_n: \text{The graph} \;\langle V, E^i \cup \{e\} \rangle \; \text{satisfies} \; P\}\neq
>     \emptyset$, then $E^{i+1}=E^i \cup \{e\}$ where $e$ is chosen randomly
>      and uniformly from $F^i$.
> 3. If $F^i=\emptyset$, then $\textbf{M}_n(P)=\langle V,E^i\rangle,$ and the construction is complete.

I am currently reading [this paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/rsa.3240060217) (also cited below), in which the above construction appears. I want to understand the underlying sample space, probability measure, and the description of $\textbf{M}_n(P)$, which I think, is a random variable. But if it is a random variable, then what is its sample space and what is its co-domain? Is the process of construction a Markov chain? I am confused here.

I have never studied stochastic processes before, but when I came across the definition of the same, I felt that it might be the way here but I am not able to precisely write the things down.

*Erdős, Paul; Suen, Stephen; Winkler, Peter*, [**On the size of a random maximal graph**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/rsa.3240060217), Random Struct. Algorithms 6, No. 2-3, 309-318 (1995). [ZBL0820.05054](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0820.05054).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sample space is the set of subgraphs of $K_n$ (though some of these may have probability zero). More precisely, $\mathbf{M}_n(P)$ is concentrated on subgraphs of $K_n$ that satisfy property $P$ and to which no edge can be added while preserving property $P$. The process has not been completely described, in that it is not specified if or how the random choice at time $i+1$ is influenced by the previous random choices. However, I think it's reasonable to assume the choices are independent (i.e., enumerate the elements of $F^i$, choose a random number $N_i$ between $1$ and $|F^i|$ at time $i$ independent of all past random choices, and let $e$ be the $N_i$th element of $F^i$).

The construction is not a Markov process, as illustrated below.

Consider an example where the property $P$ is "there exists an isolated vertex" and $V=\{1,2,3,4\}$. We have:

- $E^0=\emptyset$
- $F^0=\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\}\}$
- $e=$ a random element from $F^0$, say $e=\{1,3\}$
- $E^1 =\{\{1,3\}\}$
- $F^1 = \{\{1,2\},\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{3,4\}\}$. Note $\{1,3\}$ is removed because it has already been chosen, and $\{2,4\}$ is removed because choosing it would leave no isolated vertices.
- $e = $ a random element from $F^1$, say $e=\{2,3\}$
- $E^2 = \{\{1,3\},\{2,3\}\}$. Note at this point $4$ is the only vertex that can be isolated in $\mathbf{M}_n(P)$. This is determined by *both* of our previous edge choices, not just the most recent choice, hence the process is not Markov.
- $F^2 =\{\{1,3\}\}$ since this is the only edge not yet in the random graph that is not incident to $4$.
- $e=$ a random element from $F^2$, i.e., $e=\{1,2\}$.
- $E^3 = \{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\}\}$
- $F^3 = \emptyset$ and the construction terminates.

In this example you should be able to convince yourself that $\mathbf{M}_n(P)$ is uniform on the triangle subgraphs of $K_4$. That is, for any given triangle subgraph, with probability $\frac{1}{4}$ the construction ends in that subgraph. Note that $|F^0|=6$, $|F^1|=4$, and $|F^3|=1$ regardless of the choices we make in this example. So if edges $e_1$, $e_2$, and $e_3$ form a triangle subgraph, then they are chosen with probability $\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{4}\cdot 3!=\frac{1}{4}$ (since it doesn't matter which order we choose the edges).

In general it will be much more complicated to calculate the probability distribution of $\mathbf{M}_n(P)$. In my opinion it is best understood as being built by a random process over time.

Comment: What do you mean by "concentrated" in your second line of the first paragraph above?

Comment: At $i+1$th stage, we do choose an edge uniformly at random from $F^{i+1}$. But yeah, we don't know how it is related to the previous state.

Comment: Under $\textbf{M}_n(P)$, what will be the image of a subgraph of $K_n$ which does not follow property $P$? I think the sample space is the set of all subgraphs of $K_n$ which satisfy the property $P$.

Comment: A probability distribution $\mathbb{P}$ is concentrated on a set $A$ if $\mathbb{P}(A^C)=0$. So I mean that the only graphs that can have positive probability of occurring under $\mathbf{M}_n(P)$ are those that satisfy property $P$ and have no supergraph satisfying property $P$.

Comment: $\mathbf{M}_n(P)$ is a graph-valued random variable. The underlying probability space is some abstract space that encodes the choices of edges at each stage, e.g., $\Omega = (E\cup \{\emptyset\})^N$ where $E$ is the set of edges of $K_n$, and $N=\binom{n}{2}$. With this choice of probability space, we could encode the choices in my example above by the element $\omega = (\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2\},\emptyset,\emptyset,\dots,\emptyset) \in \Omega$. The image of this would be the triangle graph on the vertices $1,2,3$.

Comment: I have observed that more the edges in a maximal P-graph, more is the probability of its occurrence. This is because more edges mean more permutations of these edges as per the construction.

Comment: I'm not sure that necessarily holds in general. There are more permutations, but there are also more probabilities to multiply, and it's possible those probabilities are smaller (more edges to choose from).

Comment: Oh. I just checked for "P=Bipartite" and n=4. But I also feel that generalising this, if possible, not easy.